# Rails way to define parameter for filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is the following routes:

```
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do 
      resources :places, only: [:index]
    end
  end
```

The code of the controller:

```
class API::V1::PlacesController < API::V1::ApplicationController

  def index
    @places = (!params[:id]) ? Place.all : Place.find_all_by_type_id(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @places }
      format.html
    end
  end   

end
```

'Place' has 'type_id' field, and I want to filter places by its filter_id. As you can see, now I send the parameter through URL as "places?id=1". But may be I must send parameter as "places/1"? I need also to set up paths; now they doesn't work with "?id=1" form. Please, tell me, how should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Why not define two actions, one filtered, one unfiltered, and have them both render the same html / json?

Comment: Then you could have `/api/places` and `/api/places/by_type/:type_id`. It's generally not recommended to do too much in one controller method. Each method should have a specific purpose.

Comment: Thanks. Make an answer and I'll mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation is to rewrite it like this:

```
# Your routes
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do 
    resources :places, only: [:index]
    get "/places/by_type/:type_id" => "places#by_type", as: :places_by_type
  end
end

# Your controller

class API::V1::PlacesController < API::V1::ApplicationController
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @places }
      format.html
    end
  end

  def by_type
    @places = Place.where(type_id: params[:type_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render json: @places }
      format.html do
        render action: "index"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I could be slightly wrong about the routes, but I'm pretty sure it should work.

Comment: Also, please, can you show me path for 'by_type' construction? I hoped it was "api_v1_places_by_type_path(type)", but it doesn't work

Comment: I've updated my answer. Your method should work now.

Comment: The last question - should I always use "as" feature?

Comment: That adds the method you asked about. It's optional.

Comment: Thanks, but I meant match feature value doesn't convert to path automatically?

Comment: The match is only to pattern match the URL that comes into Rails. The `:as` option is to add the method to your views. There's no way to automatically create this since you can always have `/my/:crazy/path/:that/makes/:no/sense` and Rails wouldn't know how to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Rails convention would be to have the list of the places in the "index" action mapped to the relative path `/places` (GET method).

And then `/places/1` (GET) would be mapped to "show", which is intended for presenting a member of the collection. For "show", the route would assign the ID segment of the path ("1") to `params[:id]`.

[The guides have a table of default route mappings.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) The `:type_id` attribute in the model vs. the `:id` attribute in the route probably confused you.

A simple solution would be to use `/places?type_id=1` instead. In your controller, you can have something like:

```
def index
  collection = Place.all
  collection = collection.where(:type_id => params[:type_id].to_s) unless params[:type_id].to_s.blank?
  respond_to do |format|
    # ...
  end
end
```

Setting `:type_id` as a query parameter instead of integrating into the relative path seems especially reasonable to me since you are building an API and might add support for more filters in the future.

Comment: It's highly dependent on what direction this functionality goes in the long term. If you want to narrow down places by map radius, search by name, etc, then you'd create some kind of `Place::Filter` object to do all your parameter checking.